# Python Time Complexity: For Loops

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

The code below uses **nested loops** to multiply each element of `list a` with all the other elements of `list b`.
I am conscious of the fact that the time complexity for each loop is `O(n)` and that here `n` is a fairly small value, but what if `n` was too large to be processed? That is if the `lists a,b` had too large the values? How could I **alter** my code's **time complexity** then for the same function applied.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
new = []
if len(a) == len(b):
     for x in a:   # O(n)
         for y in b:   # O(n)
             new.append((x*y))
print(new)
```

Comment: You can't. Your code is doing `len(a) * len(b)` multiplications, and your code exactly represents that. Depending on what you're _doing_ with the values you may be able to generate them on the fly, stop early, etc with something like [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). But if you _need_ the cartesian product of two lists, then you can't change the complexity of taking the cartesian product of two lists.

Comment: Can't we use hashtables or something like that?

Comment: Why would hash tables be useful? Your current question is actually equivalent to having a single for loop, and asking for faster than `O(n)` iteration. Your `new` list has `len(a) * len(b)` values; hence you must create that many items, so your time complexity cannot be less than that in general.

Comment: How is my question equivalent to having a single for loop, it still takes O(n^2) complexity..

Comment: The code isn't equivalent to a single for loop but the question is. You're asking for faster-than-linear iteration; it's not possible.

Comment: Your `new` list will have n² elements (nine in this case), so you can't get below that complexity. That is, _if_ you really need all those elements. Hence the question, what exactly _do_ you need them for? If, say, you just need the sum or max of all those products, there are faster ways for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to improve your O(n^2) run-time.  n counts multiplications so you could cache values.  It would be the same complexity and your algorithm would be slower.